# Use of the Equivalence symbol in logic statements

Tags: logic

Is it correc to use the equivalence symbol to express that two statements are logically equivalent to one another? For example,

$$\forall (x_j,y_j) \in \mathbb N^{2}\,, \exists\,k \in \mathbb N\,:  y_j/x_j=1/k\equiv {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}}- \biggl\lfloor {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}
}} \biggr\rfloor =0
$$

I guess the double-ended implicative arrow would be suitable, for that matter I would very much appreciate someone explaining the difference between a statements being equivalent to another, and two statements implying one another.

Comment: You usually only use $\equiv$ for object values (terms), not for proposition values.

Answer (score 1):

First, let's add parentheses where they should:

$$\forall (x_j,y_j) \in \mathbb N^{2}\, \big( \exists\,k \in \mathbb N\,:  y_j/x_j=1/k\equiv {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}}- \biggl\lfloor {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}
}} \biggr\rfloor =0 \big)
$$

Now, what you want to use here is the symbol for the material or logical biconditional, which is the symbol used for the truth-functional operator (or connective) that combines two logic formulas into one logic formula. You definitely do *not* want to use the symbol used for logical equivalence, since that is a *meta-logical* symbol, i.e. a symbol used to make a claim *about* logic statements.

Now, confusingly, some texts use the $\equiv$ to express the material biconditional, while others use the $\equiv$ to express logical equivalence. It sounds like your text uses the $\leftrightarrow$ for the material biconditional, and that is uses $\equiv$ for logical equivalence. If so, the you should definitely use the $\leftrightarrow$, and *not* the $\equiv$

Indeed, if you want to use logical equivalence, you need to have two logic statements, but you have only one *statement* here. Sure, there are two component *parts* of that statement:

$$\exists\,k \in \mathbb N\,:  y_j/x_j=1/k$$

and

$${\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}}- \biggl\lfloor {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}} \biggr\rfloor =0 $$

but those are formulas, and not statements. Statements have truth-values, but these formulas have free variables, and thus we cannot assign any truth-value to them.

Now, there actually is such a thing as logical equivalence of logical formulas, which is defined as:

$\phi$ and $\psi$ are logically equivalent if and only if for any interpretation $I$, and any variable-assignment $v$ that sets the free variables in $\phi$ and $\psi$ to the domain of $I$, we have that $I[v] \vDash \phi$ iff $I[v] \vDash \psi$.

But, we don't have that here, since we are free to interpret any of the functions you are using here in any way we want (we could, e.g. interpret $-$ as addition, and $\lfloor \rfloor$ as square, just to pick something silly)

So, at best these statement are *mathematically/arithmetically* equivalent, but they are certainly not logically equivalent, and so you have:

$$\exists\,k \in \mathbb N\,:  y_j/x_j=1/k \not \equiv \forall (x_j,y_j) \in \mathbb N^{2}\,{\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}}- \biggl\lfloor {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}} \biggr\rfloor =0 $$

Comment: ok agreed, but in saying that, would it be any less correct if I made the exact same statement but with the bidirectional implicative arrow? I don't think it would. I feel as if only the context would decide the appropriate choice, if it were a transitionary lemma between proposition and "conclusion" of truth value of that proposition, then the double ended arrow would be chosen.

Comment: but if it were my concluding statement that indeed, these two statements are equivalent, then it would be as I chose above

Comment: @user548331 Well, you really have only one *statement* here: $\exists\,k \in \mathbb N\,:  y_j/x_j=1/k$ and ${\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}}- \biggl\lfloor {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}} \biggr\rfloor =0 $ are really just formulas, but not statements in the sense that they have a truth-value. So, if you want to talk about two *statements*, you'd need to talk about $\forall (x_j,y_j) \in \mathbb N^{2}\, \exists\,k \in \mathbb N\,:  y_j/x_j=1/k$ and $\forall (x_j,y_j) \in \mathbb N^{2}\,{\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}}- \biggl\lfloor {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}} \biggr\rfloor =0 $

Comment: @user548331 And even those two statements are not *logically* equivalent. They are mathematically/arithmetically equivalent, but not logically equivalent.

Comment: Could you elaborate on your final point by example please.

Comment: They are statements concerning a pair of formulas according to my current understanding.

Comment: your comment prior to that is not correct.combining the statements I made into one by making the declaration $\forall (x_j,y_j) \in \mathbb N^{2}: {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}}}- \biggl\lfloor {\frac {x_{{j}}}{y_{{j}}
}} \biggr\rfloor =0$ renders the truth value to be false with the negated double ended arrow as their logical connective

Comment: @user548331 Yeah, you're right, pulling them apart the way I did doesn't make much sense either. Bu this just goes to show that we have just *one statement* concerning a *pair of formulas*. And since this is a logic statement, you want to use the 'if and only if' logic symbol. Most etxts use $\leftrightarrow$ for that, but many use $\equiv$. And, unfortunately, some use $\Leftrightarrow$, though that one is a meta-logical symbol, which you definitely don't want to use here, Adding to the confusion, some texts use $\equiv$ as the meta-logical symbol for logical equivalence.

Comment: what you have stated there, is that the remainder of division of two numbers being equal to zero does not imply that they have a common integer divisor greater than one, and likewise in the opposite direction, with is of course false

Comment: ok well I am not learned in  the use of the first arrow you mentioned for logic, please provide examples of it's use or references to allow me to become so.

Comment: i am referring to the double ended $\leftarrow$, I don't even know the latex for it!

Comment: @user548331 But again, there is no logical equivalence here. The two formulas are *arithmetically* equivalent in the sense that for any two numbers $m, n \in \mathbb{N}$, we have that within the structure of the natural numbers, and using the standard interpretation for the functions involved: $\exists\,k \in \mathbb N\,:  \bar{m}/\bar{n}=1/k$ if and only if ${\frac {\bar{n}}{\bar{m}}}- \biggl\lfloor {\frac {\bar{n}}{\bar{m}}} \biggr\rfloor =0 $ where $\bar{m}$ and $\bar{n}$ are the symbolic representations of $m$ and $n$

Comment: @user548331 it's \leftrightarrow   OK, so yes, *that* one would be perfectly appropriate in the place of the $\equiv$.   In fact, if your text is using the $\equiv$ for logical equivalence, then you definitely do *not* want to use that one. You want to use the symbol for the 'material biconditional' or 'logical biconditional'. See [logical Conditional](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_biconditional). (and note the use of the $\Leftrightarrow$ there as well, which is the symbol for [logical equivalence](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Logical_equivalence).

Comment: @user548331 OK, I think I figured it out ... it all goes back to the annoying fact that some texts use $\equiv$ for the material biconditional, while others use it for logical equivalence. I thought at first your $\equiv$ was used for the material biconditional, but now I get the impression your text uses that for logical equivalence, and uses $\leftrightarrow$ for the material biconditional ... is that correct?

Comment: no honestly until now with regard to formal logic I have been using everything I learnt in my freshman year of university, which would have been approximately 2004, I haven't yet chosen a text specifically for formal logic, the closest is the one I've chosen for Abstract Algebra, and I am only in the the 3rd chapter at this point, and this level of detail for formal logic has not been covered yet

Comment: @user548331 OK, then I would advise using the $\leftrightarrow$ ... that one is pretty consistently used for the material/logical biconditional, and not for logical equivalence.

Comment: ok no problem I will make a note of this and start to familiarize with that connective much appreciated thankyou

Comment: @user548331 You're welcome!  Sorry if at first I was confusing you! I do wish there was more of a standard as far as the use of symbols goes. Good luck with your studies!

Comment: Thanks yes unfortunately I don't think using formal logic in the manner that it is imperative to number theory amongst a number of fields will ever be truly recognized because of the indirect nature of the relationship between the various fields of mathematics it is used, and expecting a standard universal notation would indeed seem logical, but in practice it is important for the individual to learn the art of conversing with others that think differently to themselves, and those others using differing notation encourages the development of this and so the ambiguity is complementary in a way